# Achieve data between particular date in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named `User`,`Role` and `Balance_updates`. `User` table hold info about user,`Role` depicts type of user like Customer,Admin,Manager and `Balance_updates` store all transaction regarding balance i.e it store history about transaction related to balance.

**Tables**

User

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| username              | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| password              | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| email                 | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| role_id               | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| mobile_wallet_balance | double(20,2) | NO   |     | 0.00              |       |
| merit_point           | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| status                | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| is_auto_btm_enabled   | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0                 |       |
| created_at            | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| updated_at            | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| gender                | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| validity              | date         | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| status_desc           | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

Role

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(25)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value       | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Balance_updates

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| role_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| amount     | double(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| updated_at | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Data in Balance_updates

**Objective**

I want to generate all users and their respective balance in any given date;
For example if i want the balance statement for a given date `2012-12-28` it should generate latest balance from `Balance_updates`.

**What I have tried**

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
u.username
), r.value, u.amount AS `amount`
FROM Balance_updates u
INNER JOIN Role r ON u.role_id = r.id
WHERE u.amount > 0.0 && UNIX_TIMESTAMP( u.updated_at ) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2013-1-3 23:59:59' )
ORDER BY r.value, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( u.updated_at ) DESC
```

**RESULT and PROBLEM**

As you expect it is returning all values from Balance_updates i.e every other User transaction recorded.

Question:

1.How can i achieve latest balance statement of a user in a particular date.If in that date user balance is not changed then show his balance in previous time last changed.

Any help will be appreciated;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not tested, but I have the feeling this could work (and could be optimised).*

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.username, r.value, u.amount AS `amount`
FROM Balance_updates u
INNER JOIN Role r ON u.role_id = r.id
WHERE u.updated_at = (
    SELECT MAX(inner_u.updated_at)
    FROM Balance_updates AS inner_u
    WHERE
        inner_u.username = u.username
        && amount > 0
        && UNIX_TIMESTAMP( inner_u.updated_at ) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2013-1-3 23:59:59' )
)
ORDER BY r.value, UNIX_TIMESTAMP( u.updated_at ) DESC
```

Just one off-topic piece of advice:

- add a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to table `User` (e.g. `User.id`); make it the primary key
- replace column `Balance_updates.username` with (e.g.) `Balance_updates.user_id`, and store a reference to `User.id` (a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)).

or

- change column `Balance_updates.username` to a `VARCHAR(20)` to match the type of `User.username`

Comment: sorry for late reply....but thanks it works...AND i would workout my database as you have suggested...again Thanks..